# Java Timer not working. Calling Multiple Timers at Once

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I started making a game using Java. I am currently working on a basic enemy that will fire in range and when it fires I want it to wait for x seconds and fire 3 bullets at a rate of y.

So I decided to use a Timer to create this delay:

```
public class DelayFire
{
    Toolkit toolkit;

    Timer timer;
    //The enemy firing
    Enemy com;

    public DelayFire(double seconds, Enemy e, boolean un)
    {
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        timer = new Timer();
        com = e;
        timer.schedule(new FireTask(un), (int) seconds * 1000);
    }

    class FireTask extends TimerTask
    {
        public boolean unfire = false;

        public FireTask (boolean x)
        {
            this.unfire = x;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            if(com.health>0)
            {
                com.charging = false;
                com.fire();
                if(unfire==true)
                {
                    com.fire = false;
                    com.canFire = true;
                }
                this.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then which I call in Enemy class it 3 times each with a different delay:

```
void spray()
{
    new DelayFire(2.0,this,false);
    new DelayFire(2.5,this,false);
    new DelayFire(3.0,this,true);
}
```

This void is called when ever the player is in firing range (This is also in the Enemy class):

```
if(canFire==true && fire==false)
{
    spray();
    canFire = false;
    fire = true;
}
```

Yet after all this work it will only create two bullets once I'm within range. Until I leave and re-enter the enemy's sight again.

Note: I only put the parts of my code where I would expect some mistake is made. Let me know if you need to see more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure only two bullets are fired? You can try inserting `System.out.println("Hello, Bullet World!")` in the `run()` method of `FireTask`. You might be surprised to find that the line will print three times.

What you're experiencing is the associativity of casts. Consider this part of your code:

```
(int) seconds * 1000
```

Since `seconds` is a double, and you want an int (or perhaps a long), it's natural that you'll want to cast it. However, the cast does not cast the entire expression `seconds * 1000` to an int - just `seconds`. Next, consider your instantiations of your `DelayFire` class:

```
new DelayFire(2.0,this,false);
new DelayFire(2.5,this,false);
new DelayFire(3.0,this,true);
```

Here, you use the double values `2.0`, `2.5`, and `3.0`. However, the `2.5` is casted to an int before the multiplication, causing it to become a flat `2`. As a result, your program will schedule two bullets to be fired after 2 seconds, and one bullet to be fired after 3 seconds.

To get around this problem, stick some parentheses around the entire expression with the multiplication in it:

```
(int) (seconds * 1000)
```

This should result in the correct behavior. There may be other bugs in your code, though. But try that first.

**Edit:** As a side note, the conditions in your `if`-statements are overcomplicated. You are basically turning a boolean-valued expression into another boolean-valued expression by writing `if (unfire == true)`. Since `unfire` *is* a boolean expression, there is no need for the `==` operator. You can simply write `if (unfire)`. And instead of checking if the value is false, use the unary `!`-operator to *negate* the expression, `if (!unfire)`.